# Serving ESRI layer as WMS through QGIS server

Tags: openlayers, wms, qgis-server, arcgis-online-basemaps

I added ESRI's [World Hillshade](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1b243539f4514b6ba35e7d995890db1d) layer through *Add Layer -> Add ArcGIS Mapserver Layer...* and it shows up correctly in QGIS. Now I want to use it as base layer for a online map. I try to offer it as WMS service using QGIS server to later visualize it with OpenLayers.

The problem is that *GetCapabilities* doesn't include the layer and so I get a *LayerNotDefined ServiceException* when calling the WMS service.

The only suspicious thing I see on QGIS site is that the layer properties show a *exportTilesAllowed=false*. Could this be the reason that it's not offered as WMS data, does QGIS server have in mind this property?

Should it generally be possible to serve ArcGIS Map Server layers with QGIS server to web sites?

Comment: I just noticed that this question is dumb: There is no need to serve ArcGIS Layers with QGIS. You can load ArcGIS Mapserver Layers directly using OpenLayers ol.source.TileArcGISRest tile source.